# Tensor products of group algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, group-rings

We know that if $G$ and $H$ are finite groups and $F_p$ is a field of characteristics $p$, then $$F_pG\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} F_pH\cong F_p(G\times H).$$ Here $\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} $ denotes the tensor products of group algebras over $F_p$.

My question is whether or not there exists any such isomorphism in case of semi-direct products or not, i.e. $$F_pG_1\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} F_pG_2 \ \underbrace{\cong}_{?}F_p(G\rtimes H),$$ where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are groups related to $G$ and $H$ in some way. Please help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_product